# Insert Multiple Data in to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Good day I just want to ask if this is possible because I only creating a date 1 by 1

I want to generate a range of date

for example

I have

```
datefrom = 09/01/2023   
dateto = 09/15/2023
```

Answer

Database must insert date within range

| fix_date |
| --- |
| 09/01/2023 |
| 09/02/2023 |
| 09/03/2023 |
| 09/04/2023 |
| ... |
| 09/15/2023 |

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetime" class="control-label">Time In</label>
    <input type="date" name="datefrom" id="datefrom" min="" max=""
           onchange="updateDate()" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0"
           required
    >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="datetime" class="control-label">Time Out</label>
    <input type="date" name="datetime_to" id="datetime_to" min="" max=""
           class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0"
           required
    >
</div>
```

This is my code for generating the range that i chose but i dont know how will i create a php code for multiple data

```
<form action="" id="report-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($id) ? $id : '' ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<?php echo isset($project_id) ? $project_id : '' ?>">
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date_from" class="control-label">Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="fix_date" id="fix_date" readonly min="" max=""   class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($fix_date) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fix_date)) : '' ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="datetime" class="control-label">Time In</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime_from" id="datetime_from" min="" max="" onclick="setDefaultTime()" onchange="updateDate()" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0"  value="<?php echo isset($datetime_from) ? date("Y-m-d\TH:i",strtotime($datetime_from)) : '' ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="datetime" class="control-label">Time Out</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime_to" id="datetime_to" min="" max="" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($datetime_to) ? date("Y-m-d\TH:i",strtotime($datetime_to)) : '' ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="duration" class="control-label">Total Number of Hours(Reg)</label>
            <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" oninput="validateregular()"  class="form-control  form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($duration) ? $duration : '' ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="duration" class="control-label">Total No. of Hours (OT)</label>
            <input type="text" name="overtime" id="overtime" oninput="validateovertime()"  class="form-control  form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($overtime) ? $overtime : '' ?>" >
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="duration" class="control-label">Late/Undertime (in Hour)s</label>
            <input type="text" name="undertime" id="undertime" oninput="validateundertime()"  class="form-control  form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($duration) ? $undertime : '' ?>" >
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
            <label for="duration" class="control-label">Late/Undertime (in Hour)s</label>
            <input type="text" name="undertime" id="undertime" oninput="validateundertime()"  class="form-control  form-control-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo isset($duration) ? $undertime : '' ?>" >
        </div>



      
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="sickleave">Sick Leave</label>
            <br>
                <input type="radio" id="sickleave" name="sickleave" value="1" <?php echo isset($sickleave) && $sickleave == "1" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="sickleave" name="sickleave" value="0" <?php echo isset($sickleave) && $sickleave == "0" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">No</label>
            <br>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="sickleave">Vacation Leave</label>
            <br>
                <input type="radio" id="vacation" name="vacation" value="1" <?php echo isset($vacation) && $vacation == "1" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="vacation" name="vacation" value="0" <?php echo isset($vacation) && $vacation == "0" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">No</label>
            <br>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="sickleave">Holiday</label>
            <br>
                <input type="radio" id="holiday" name="holiday" value="1" <?php echo  isset($holiday) && $holiday == "1" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" id="holiday" name="holiday" value="0" <?php echo isset($holiday) &&  $holiday == "0" ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                <label for="sickleave">No</label>
            <br>
        </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
            <textarea rows="3" name="description" id="description" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" required><?php echo isset($description) ? html_entity_decode($description) : '' ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```php
$_POST['description'] = htmlentities($_POST['description']);
$_POST['employee_id'] = $this->settings->userdata('id');
$_POST['duration'] = htmlentities($_POST['duration']) ;
extract($_POST);

$data = "";
foreach($_POST as $k =>$v){
    
    if(!in_array($k,array('id'))){
        
        if(!is_numeric($v))
            $v = $this->conn->real_escape_string($v);
        
        if(!empty($data)) 
            $data .=",";

        $data .= " `{$k}`='{$v}' ";
    }
}

if(empty($id)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `report_list` set {$data} ";
}else{
    $sql = "UPDATE `report_list` set {$data} where id = '{$id}' ";
}

$check = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM `report_list` where `date_from` = '{$date_from}' and `employee_id` = '{$employee_id}' and `project_id` = '{$project_id}' and id != '{$id}' ")->num_rows;

if($check > 0){
    
    $resp['status'] = 'failed';
    $resp['msg'] = 'Date already exists for this employee.';

}else{
    
    $save = $this->conn->query($sql);

    if($save){
        
        $rid = !empty($id) ? $id : $this->conn->insert_id;
        $resp['id'] = $rid;
        $resp['status'] = 'success';
        
        if(empty($id))
            $resp['msg'] = "Attendance has successfully added.";
        else
            $resp['msg'] = "Attendance details has been updated successfully.";
    }else{
        
        $resp['status'] = 'failed';
        $resp['msg'] = "An error occured.";
        $resp['err'] = $this->conn->error."[{$sql}]";
    }
}

if($resp['status'] =='success')
    $this->settings->set_flashdata('success',$resp['msg']);

return json_encode($resp);
```

this is my code on generating 1 by 1 data